# Online view of a polyhedron defined by linear inequalities

Tags: linear-programming, polygons, polyhedra, online-resources, simplex

I am studying the simplex algorithm which finds an optimal solution for a minimization or a maximization of a set of linear inequalities.

I know that such a set of inequalities defines a polyhedron. My question is this :is there an online tool that allows me to input linear inequalities with two or three variables and see the polyhedron defined by them? This would be the set of all points which satisfy all inequalities.

Comment: see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_enumeration_problem)

Comment: See an answer to you question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19361/polyhedron-visualisation Sergey P. Shary

Answer (score 4):

You can, with [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org). Specifically, Sage has a [web-interface](https://sagecell.sagemath.org) or [online workspace](https://cloud.sagemath.com) that requires zero installation (although you may need to create an account).

Here's an example. If you type

```
p = Polyhedron(ieqs = [[0,0,0,2],[0,0,1,0,],[0,10,0,0],
                      [1,-1,0,0],[1,0,-1,0,],[1,0,0,-1]])
p.plot()
```

you will receive [this picture](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwrULBVCMjPqcxITSnKz9PITC0sBopERxvogKBRrA6YZQjEYKYhWDxWh5dLASuINtTRNYQoiQbRulCdYDEgLzZWk5erQK8gJ79EQxMAOgcbww==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==):

[image: somehow, a cube is born]

(In Sage/Python, anything in a line after # will be a comment; that `p.Hrepresentation()` business was me trying to figure out what the inequalities were)).

I've really never used Sage for this, so this example is taken from [this documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/representation.html) about $V$- and $H$-representations of polytopes.

I was seriously confused by how `[0, 0, 0, 2]` counts as an inequality, but that's explained in this [thematic tutorial on polytopes in Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/geometry/polyhedra_quicktutorial.html).

Apparently if a list $[d, a, b, c]$ is given when an inequality is expected, it's the inequality $(a, b, c) \cdot \vec x + d \ge 0$. It seems then that an inequality $ax + by + cz \ge d$ would be represented by the list `[-d, a, b, c]`, and an inequality $ax + by + cz \le d$ by `[d, -a, -b, -c]` (I think).

At any rate, picking up Sage isn't too bad, but it does take some legwork, usually, to do anything that isn't immediately straightforward. It's been immensely helpful to me over the years, so it's worth a shot: it definitely *can* do what you want, if you have a bit of patience (and obviously some programming experience is a plus!).

If you do decide to give it a shot, I'd be more than happy to *try* to help out with things you're not sure about.

Answer (score 2):

In 2D, there's [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/PlottingAndGraphics.html), of course. There is also [Desmos's graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator):

[image]

And there's [GeoGebra's graphing calculator](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, do you know of any 3D tool. I have seen an example in Wolfram where the plot was 3D but the z represented the cost of the vector (x, y) and not another variable

Comment: @Belgi https://www.geogebra.org/3d allows one to create vertices and faces of polyhedra. Perhaps one can write a script that creates a GeoGebra file describing a polyhedron, and then one can visualize the polyhedron online.

Comment: @Belgi Just found the https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/ConvexHull_Command

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Unfortunately, Geogebra's convex hull is apparently only in the $x,y$ plane. https://help.geogebra.org/topic/convexhull_1

Answer (score 0):

A good and completely free MATLAB-based visualization package for 2D and 3D  polyhedrons, which are solution sets to systems of linear algebraic inequalities, is lineq2. Its description can be found in the neighboring thread at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19361/polyhedron-visualisation

The input data, the system matrix and its right-hand side vector, are entered in MATLAB syntax, which, in my opinion, is more convenient than what is offered by Sage.

The output of the visualization program is a list of vertices of the polyhedral solution set, which can even be unbounded or meager. See examples at the link above.